# SQL UPDATE ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row calculating percentage

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is the table i have that i want to put the percentages.

```
+------+--------+-------------+--------------+
| H_ID | H_NAME | DOCTOR_STAT | PATIENT_STAT |
+------+--------+-------------+--------------+
|    1 | NAME 1 |           0 |             0|
|    2 | NAME 2 |           0 |             0|
|    3 | NAME 3 |           0 |             0|
|    4 | NAME 4 |           0 |             0|
|    5 | NAME 5 |           0 |             0|
+------+--------+-------------+--------------+
```

This is the code i have written. The inner sql-query works fine (it prints correctly the percentage of said hospital id) but it returns multiple rows so the update doesn't work.

```
UPDATE HOSPITAL_STATISTICS
SET DOCTOR_STAT=(SELECT ROUND(100*COUNT(DOCTOR.WORK_HOSPITAL)/(SELECT COUNT(DOCTOR.ID)FROM DOCTOR),2)
FROM DOCTOR,HOSPITAL
WHERE HOSPITAL.HOSPITAL_ID=DOCTOR.WORK_HOSPITAL
GROUP BY HOSPITAL.HOSPITAL_ID)
```

I know this returns multiple rows but i don't know how to solve this. I must calculate the percentages of how many doctors are working on every hospital. If you need more table data for help please tell me :)

EDIT:I have a second table named Patient_Visit and a third one Hospital

```
Patient_Visit
[Visit_ID,Patient_ID,Hospital_ID]

Hospital
[Hospital_ID,Hospital_Name]
```

and im trying to do the same thing with this code

```
UPDATE HOSPITAL_STATISTICS
SET PATIENT_STAT=(SELECT ROUND(100* COUNT (*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PATIENT_VISIT),2)
FROM PATIENT_VISIT,HOSPITAL
WHERE PATIENT_VISIT.HOSPITAL_ID=HOSPITAL.HOSPITAL_ID AND HOSPITAL_STATISTICS.H_ID=PATIENT_VISIT.HOSPITAL_ID
GROUP BY HOSPITAL_VISIT.HOSPITAL_ID)
```

which gives me this error:ORA-01407: cannot update ("HOSPITAL_STATISTICS"."PATIENT_STAT") to NULL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a correlated subquery, not a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE HOSPITAL_STATISTICS HS
    SET DOCTOR_STAT = (SELECT ROUND(100 * COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DOCTOR), 2)
                       FROM DOCTOR D
                       WHERE HS.H_ID = D.WORK_HOSPITAL
                      );
```

Comment: You are the best. Thanks for the help. Can you briefly explain what are you doing in the query differently?

Comment: @spirothedragon . . . This is using a correlated subquery, so the inner query is not returning results for all rows.

Comment: @gordonlinoff..Can you please check the edit i did? When i have to join two tables it doesn't work.

Comment: @spirothedragon . . . You should ask a *new* question.  The question  you originally asked here has been answered.